# When I clicked a one button, all button automatically clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks

Currently, I am creating a static ticket booking application for self-learning react. I use Bootstrap for styling

When I select the ticket count, it opens up in Seat Select:
[image]

```
const [select,setSelect]=useState(0);
const [seatCount,setSeatCount]=useState(select);
const [toggleSeat,setToggleSeat]=useState(false);

const ticketCountHandler=(e)=>{
    setSelect(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setSeatCount(e.target.value)
  }

const ticketCount=Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => index + 1);
  

  const seatCountHandler=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setToggleSeat(!toggleSeat); 

    if(!toggleSeat){
       setSeatCount(prev=>prev-1)
    }else{
      setSeatCount(prev=>prev+1)
    }
 }
```

**seat count dropdown menu:**

```
{/*count inputl start */}
              <div className="col-4">
              <select id="count" value={select} onChange={ticketCountHandler} className='form-select'>
                  <option selected disabled hidden>Select Ticket Count(max 10)</option>
                  {ticketCount.map((value) => (
                  <option key={value} value={value}>
                           {value}
                      </option>
                   ))}
                  
                </select>
              </div>
              {/*count input end */}
```

**seat selection model:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn form-control" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#seat-count">
  Select Seats
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="seat-count" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Your Ticket Count {seatCount}</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-1"></div>
          <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className='btn seat-btn disabled bg-danger'>100</button></div>
          <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={101} onClick={seatCountHandler}>101</button></div>
          <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={102} onClick={seatCountHandler}>102</button></div>
          <div className="col-1"></div>
          <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={103} onClick={seatCountHandler}>103</button></div>
          <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={104} onClick={seatCountHandler}>104</button></div>
          <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={105} onClick={seatCountHandler}>105</button></div>
          <div className="col-1"></div>
          <div className="col-1"></div>
        </div>
```

My problem is, now when I click on one button, all buttons are suddenly colored and the count only changes once even after clicking many buttons:

[image]

I need help to fix this issue, since last week I have been stuck in this issue, trying so many related questions, using Chatgpt/bard, and watching some yt videos..still can't fix this issue.

Comment: I have provided an answer below; let me know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short and simple answer, you have one common `toggleSeat` for all seat buttons - whenever a seat is selected, and `toggleSeat` becomes true, all button would apply the style of `bg-success`:

```
// Using the second group as an example, 
// they all rely on the same toggleSeat for className.
<div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={103} onClick={seatCountHandler}>103</button></div>
<div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={104} onClick={seatCountHandler}>104</button></div>
<div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeat?"bg-success":""}`} value={105} onClick={seatCountHandler}>105</button></div>
```

And you have multiple methods to fix this, you can of course turn `select` state into an `Object`, or change `toggleSeat` state into an `array`.

But I'd provide another one for you.

---

You can use `Set()` to your advantage (explanation in codes):

```
// ...other useState()
const [toggleSeats, setToggleSeats] = useState(new Set());

const seatCountHandler=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Convert the value to a number (optional).
    let numberChagned = Number(e.target.value);
    // Check if the Set() has the number,
    if (!toggleSeats.has(numberChanged)) {
        setToggleSeats(prev => new Set(prev.add(numberChanged));
        setSeatCount(prev => prev - 1);
    } else {
        setToggleSeats(prev => {
            prev.delete(numberChanged);
            return new Set(prev);
        };
        setSeatCount(prev => prev + 1);
    }
}

// ...other functions

return (
    // ...other parts of jsx
    // Check for specific values in the Set for each button.
    <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeats.has(103) ? "bg-success" : ""}`} value={103} onClick={seatCountHandler}>103</button></div>
    <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeats.has(104) ? "bg-success" : ""}`} value={104} onClick={seatCountHandler}>104</button></div>
    <div className="col-1 m-2"><button className={`btn seat-btn ${toggleSeats.has(105) ? "bg-success" : ""}`} value={105} onClick={seatCountHandler}>105</button></div>
}
```

---

Be careful that this problem also happened for you in `setSelect()` - currently it would only store one value;

And by using `Set()` you could combine `select` state with `toggleSeat` state but not using `Object` or `array`:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Set());
// remove the below one, and then apply the rest in the above codeblock:
// const [toggleSeat,setToggleSeat] = useState(false);

// ...other codes
```